# MPMoviePlayerController + Movie get pause after it start buffering the data

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.2

In my application I am using MPMoviePlayerController to play movie from URL. initially for 2-4 secs it play well , but after that for each buffering it pauses the movie and Manually I need to play though ....

```
shouldAutoplay = YES; is set
```

I have debugged with loadstate (`iDemoPlayer.loadState` ) it is showing value 5 ( no relation )

can anyone help me on this?

Thanks,

Sagar

Answer (score 0):

loadState is a bitmask, so:

```
loadState = 5 = MPMovieLoadStatePlayable & MPMovieLoadStateStalled
```

You can listen for the `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` and manually start playback yourself when it's no longer stalled.

Comment: Did you find any resolution to it?